# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 "closeAndClearTokenInformation" method no working

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk, logout

I just upgraded from Facebook iOS SDK 3.0.X to 3.1.1, and rewrote some code...

As per Facebook documentation for the logout workflow (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/#step3), I'm calling the **closeAndClearTokenInformation** method of the **FBSession.activeSession** object.

This seems to have no effect on the Facebook session state, because checking it right after the call still returns an open session.

As it stands, once my application logs in with Facebook, it doesn't logout.

**[UPDATE 1]**

As requested, here's the code I use to check the session state:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded && FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
 //logged in
else
 //not logged in
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

Changed my logic a bit... Altered my original code to:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
 //logged in
else
 //not logged in
```

Because **FBSession.activeSession.state** was returning **FBSessionStateOpen**, not **FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded**.

Comment: can you post code on how you are checking for state? This method works as expected for me.

Comment: Added the code, as requested... Thanks for the attention.

Comment: After calling closeAndClearTokenInformation my FBSession.activeSession.state property is correctly set to "FBSessionStateClosed" and your condition above returns "not logged in".

Do your check immediately after calling closeAndClearTokenInformation and see what it returns. It correctly reached //not logged in for me.

Comment: Did as you recommended and it helped me find a flaw in my logic. Fixed it (see update 2) and it's working now.

Comment: refer the other answer it works, that should have been the selected answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe this will help.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/497294866962479?browse=search_507cb8ebc4f025673237228

I call all these methods together to make sure it is really logout. Crazy bugs.

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Comment: even after writing these lines it opens up old session next time.

Comment: I have used above 3 lines. It crashes in iOS8.

Comment: Nope, these 3 lines work fine on iOS 8 (at least 8.1.2). I had the exact same problem: my session was still open after calling `closeAndClearTokenInformation`. The suggested lines make it work OK.

Answer (score 6):

I know this may be late but on Android (3.0 SDK) the Session.getActiveSession() may return null if you're not in the same Context where you created it (or if the app was closed and the session didn't get somehow restored). It happens and it's handled by the SDK so there isn't much you can really do.

In those cases, calling closeAndClearTokenInformation() doesn't do much (if you take a look at the source code you will understand why). The solution to me was something along these lines (in Java):

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null) {
   Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
   Session.getActiveSession().close();
   Session.setActiveSession(null);
} else {
   // construct a new session (there are different ways to do this, this is how I do it because I need to pass the FACEBOOK_API_KEY programmatically).
   session = new Session.Builder(MyApp.getInstance()).setApplicationId(Constants.FACEBOOK_API_KEY).build();
   if (session != null) {//to be safe
     //beware with the case of Session vs sesssion.
     Session.setActiveSession(session); 
     session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
     session.close();
     Session.setActiveSession(null);
   }
}
```

This effectively leaves my session as:

```
{Session state:CREATED, token:{AccessToken token: permissions:[]}, appId:xxxxx}
```

Remember that created is not the same as Closed (or Open). 
From that state you can re-open the session without problems.

Hope this helps.